# ¿Como guardar la posicióno y/o registro en una BD, de un elemento del option que es movido de un select tipo lista a otro select?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

#En el siguiente código se muestran dos select de tipo lista, los cuales contienen elementos u valores definidos, al pulsar los botones que indican flechas mueve el elemento seleccionado de un selec a otro en mocas palabras cambiando de posición el elemento as i mismo un botón para subir y bajar este, LO QUE REQUIERO ES GUARDAR EN UNA BASE DE DATOS QUE DENOMINE PRUEBA1 A SI LA TABLA, PARA REGISTRAR ESTOS "MOVIMIENTOS" (como si se guardara por posición recorrer ese mismo elemento como si fuera una sola variable ) , la cual no funciona correctamente no muestra errores pero no registra nada en la tabla.#

```js
function moveUp(selectId) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
    var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 1; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
        var opt = selectOptions[i];
        if (opt.selected) {
            selectList.removeChild(opt);
            selectList.insertBefore(opt, selectOptions[i - 1]);
        }
       }
}
  
function moveDown(selectId) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
    var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = selectOptions.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        var opt = selectOptions[i];
        if (opt.selected) {
           var nextOpt = selectOptions[i + 1];
           opt = selectList.removeChild(opt);
           nextOpt = selectList.replaceChild(opt, nextOpt);
           selectList.insertBefore(nextOpt, opt);
        }
       }
}
function swapElement(fromList,toList){
    var selectOptions = document.getElementById(fromList);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
        var opt = selectOptions[i];
        if (opt.selected) {
            document.getElementById(fromList).removeChild(opt);
            document.getElementById(toList).appendChild(opt);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="OneOfTwo" style="width:60%">
 <form action="enviar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
    <div style="float:left;">
        <strong>Left</strong>
        <select id="available" neme="origen" size="5"  style="width: 80px;">
        <option>Left 1</option>
        <option>Left 2</option>
        <option>Left 3</option>
        <option>Left 4</option>
        <option>Left 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;height:50px;padding-top:28px;">
        <input type="button" value="&lt;" onclick="swapElement('selected','available')">
        <input type="button" value="&gt;" onclick="swapElement('available','selected')">
    </div>
    <div style="float:raigt;">
        <strong>Right</strong>
        <select id="selected" name="destino[]" size="5" style="width: 80px;">
        <option value="">Right 1</option>
        <option value="">Right 2</option>
        <option value="">Right 3</option>
        <option value="">Right 4</option>
        <option value="">Right 5</option>
        </select>
         
        <input type="button" value="UP" onclick=" moveUp('selected')">
        <input type="button" value="DOWN" onclick="moveDown('selected')">
    </div>
    <a id="heading-acceso" href="color.html"><button type="submit" value="enviar">Registrar</button></center>
</div>
</form>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<!-- EST ES MI PHP:
<?php
 $hoy = date("j-n-Y");
 $conexion =  new mysqli('localhost','root','','db_ciss');
 $conexion -> set_charset('utf8mb4');
 
  //nos aseguramos de que el usuario presionó enviar
  if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

    //los serializamos para guardarlo en la BD
    $origenArr = serialize($_POST['origen']);
    $destinoArr = serialize($_POST['destino']);

  
$query_agregar = $conexion -> query("INSERT INTO prueba1(Id_Prueba, valor) VALUES ('$origenArr')");
$query_agregar = $conexion -> query("SELECT * FROM prueba1");
if(mysqli_query($conexion,$query_agregar)){
    echo "Datos insertados Correctamente";
        }

}
?>
<a id="heading-acceso" href="color.html">Regresar</a>-->
```

Comment: Los `select` solo envían la opción seleccionada y vas a tener que recurrir a Javascript para hacer que se seleccionen todas las opciones al enviar el formulario.

Comment: Aparte de eso, no debes mezclar programación por procedimientos con programación con objetos y, definitivamente, tienes un error en la consulta, porque especificas dos columnas, pero solo proporcionas un valor.

Comment: te hace falta todo el php que guarda los datos... no puedes hacerlo directamente desde el javascirpt no es recomendado.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Es en donde no sé exactamente como guardar en el segundo select una vez q pase el valor del primer selec al segundo valga la redundancia ya q el elemento del option es agregado desde una función de JavaScript como recoger ese valor, que no está definido como tal en el option.@ArcanisGK507